# How do I retrieve the files from localstorage by the extension name ".log"?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to angular/js/ionic. I have a really quick question.

How do I retrieve data from localstorage when I don't really know the index name? I just want to grab whatever ends with ".log"?

I understand that the code below will try to retrieve the data by the index 'notes'.

```
var logFile = angular.fromJson(window.localStorage['notes'] || '[]');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var localLogFile = function() {
   for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
      var keyName = localStorage.key(i);
      var extension = keyName.substring(keyName.lastIndexOf("."));
      if(extension == ".log") {
         return localStorage.getItem(keyName);
      }
   }
};

var logFile = angular.fromJson(localLogFile());
```